# send multiple responses to client via nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

i am using nodejs and i want to send back multiple responses to client.And my code is below

//addwork

```
var agenda = require('../../schedules/job-schedule.js')(config.db);

    exports.addwork = function(req, res) {

        var work = new Work(req.body);
        work.user = req.user._id;
        var user=req.user;
     work.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {

                console.log('created work....'+work);
                console.log('dateeeeeeeeeeeee'+work.created);
                console.log('calling agenda job now, user is: '+ JSON.stringify(req.user));
                    console.log('supervisor-------------------------'+JSON.stringify(user.supervisor));
                agenda.now('Work_To_Supervisior_Notify', {supervisor:user.supervisor,title:work.title,details:work.details});

    res.jsonp(work);
                    res.send({message:'An email has been sent to ' + user.supervisor + ' with further instructions.'});

            }
        });
    };`
```

//job-schedule.js

```
var Agenda = require("agenda");
    var emailJob = require('./jobs/email-job.js');
module.exports = function(agendaDb) {

    var agenda = new Agenda({db: { address: agendaDb}});


    emailJob.sendWorkToSupervisiorEmail(agenda);

    agenda.start();
    return agenda;
}
```

//email-job.js

```
   exports.sendWorkToSupervisiorEmail = function(agenda){
        agenda.define('Work_To_Supervisior_Notify',{priority: 'high', concurrency: 10}, function(job, done){
            console.log('Send works to supervisior ' + JSON.stringify(job.attrs.data.supervisor)+' ,title '+job.attrs.data.title+' ,details '+job.attrs.data.details);
            var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(config.mailer.options);
                var mailOptions = {
                    to: job.attrs.data.supervisor,
                    from: config.mailer.from,
                    subject: 'work done by user',
                    html: '<b>work title : '+job.attrs.data.title+' <br/>work details : '+job.attrs.data.details+'</b>'
                };

                    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log('An email has been sent to ' + job.attrs.data.supervisor + ' with further instructions.');
                    res.send({message:'An email has been sent to ' + user.supervisor + ' with further instructions.'}); 

                    }
                });

            done();
        })

    }
```

Here i want response either from agenda or from res.send() message in addwork function
If i use res.send in addwork function it shows ERROR as "can't set headers after they sent".And if i use res.send message in sendWorkToSupervisiorEmail() it show ERROR as "there is no method send".I am new to nodejs please help me with solution

Comment: You can't send response multiple times. To do what you're trying to achieve you need to look at libraries like socket.io

Answer (score 5):

A http request only gets a single http response. Using http, you only get one response. Some options for you:

1) Wait for everything to finish before replying. Make sure each part creates a result, success or failure, and send the multiple responses at once. You would need some control flow library such as [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [Promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) to make sure everything responded at the same time. A good choice if all parts will happen "quickly", not good if your user is waiting "too long" for a response. (Those terms were in quotes, because they are application dependent).

2) Create some scheme where the first response tells how many other responses to wait for. Then you'd have a different HTTP request asking for the first additional message, and when that returns to your client, ask for the second additional message, and so on. This is a lot of coordination though, as you'd have to cache responses, or even try again if they were not done yet. Using a memory cache like redis (or similar) could fulfill the need to holding responses until ready, with a non-existent meaning 'not ready'

3) Use an eventing protocol, such as WebSockets, that can **push** messages from the server. This is a good choice, especially if you don't know how long some events would occur after the trigger. (You would not want to stall a HTTP request for tens of seconds waiting for 3 parts to complete - user will get bored, or quit, or re-submit.). Definitely check out the [Primus](https://github.com/primus/primus) library for this option. It can even serve the client-side script, which makes integration quick and easy.