# How do you send multiple response to user from the bot?

Tags: c#, node.js, botframework

I am using Microsoft Bot Framework and trying to send multiple responses to user but not sure how to do that from nodejs. I am able to do that from C#.

C# code example

```
var connector = new ConnectorClient();
connector.Messages.SendMessage(incomingMessage.CreateReplyMessage("Yo, I heard you 1.", "en"));
connector.Messages.SendMessage(incomingMessage.CreateReplyMessage("Yo, I heard you 2.", "en"));
connector.Messages.SendMessage(incomingMessage.CreateReplyMessage("Yo, I heard you 3.", "en"));
```

What would this be in **nodejs**?

nodejs code example that I'm trying to run:

```
var bot = new builder.TextBot();
bot.add('/', function (session) {
   session.send('Hello World');
   session.send('Hello World'); // won't work.
});

bot.listenStdin();
```

Comment: I'm trying session.send("Text message") and that seems to end the session right there @Wjdavis5

Comment: Please add the nodejs code to the question. You are asking us to help fix a problem with your node app but you provided a c# code snip.

Comment: @Wjdavis5, thank you for the suggestion and I've made the changes.

Comment: I must be missing something here. You said you are trying to send multiple responses but in your example you are only sending a single response.

Comment: I hope you can see the updated question now? I'm just curious to know what would be the alternative to c# code in nodejs. Thank you.

Comment: I built the Node version of the library so let me ask a did you try this using the TextBot? Your code above should definitely work. If you were actually having problems getting multiple sends working using the BotConnectorBot and the emulator I know what the issue is (look closely at the testBot example) and I can answer your question.

Comment: @StevenIckman thank you! just got the answer from the GitHub repo. That works!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this answer: [send multiple responses to client via nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902277/send-multiple-responses-to-client-via-nodejs)

You may want simulate the multiple responses(**solution 1**) that you want by returning an array property with the response object. In this case it might be helpful using this lib: https://github.com/caolan/async if you are using multiple asynchronous functions.

```
var messages = [];
messages.push('message 1');
messages.push('message 2');
// etc

response.send({all: messages});
```

However if you are not able to so so I would recommend the **solution 3** since it will keep your code cleaner & most complex web apps use websockets anyway for making the website to not require refreshed for any new data that are needed to be retrieved.

A commonly used library for websockets is socketio: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

I would not mess with **solution 2** unless the functionality is super complicated and requires acknowledgement from the client as well. In that case you could still use **solution 3.**